# Postman Response download is NOT pretty in Atom and other editors

Tags: json, parsing, postman

While using Postman and Sending and Downloading a Request, I have saved the JSON locally and when opening in Atom, Notepad++ and other editors, the Postman JSON is **not** parsed.  I've tried changing LF in Atom and it doesn't seem to do anything.  See below which shows (on the right pane) a pretty pane that parses nicely from a different project.

I don't see any settings in Postman to change nor is there an option to change when downloading.  Any ideas?

[image: Examples of JSON]

Comment: Are there not plugins to just pretty print the json within atom?

Comment: Ah.  My ignorant use of Atom and knowledge of its abilities.  Thank you.